# How to set the port in HTTParty

Tags: ruby, ssl, httparty

I read that HTTParty uses SSL [if the port is set to 443](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/07/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited/), but I don't see how to set the port. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the specs:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/82a90c1b93b076f9d2d7410123c2b5d609401a1f/spec/httparty/request_spec.rb#L41

The target URL is expected to use port 443. Just adding the `:443` at the end of the target URI should be enough to make HTTParty use SSL.

By the way, HTTPS URLs will use SSL too.

Examples:

```
http://foo.com     => no SSL
https://foo.com    => SSL
http://foo.com:443 => SSL
```

Comment: +1. Best to specify `https://` in the URL, as the port will default to 443 automatically.

Comment: Agreed with @MarkThomas . Good to know that you can use both anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It actually uses HTTPS by default unless the port is 80 and the request is HTTP:

```
context "using port 80" do
  let(:uri) { URI 'http://foobar.com' }
  it { should_not use_ssl }
end

context "using port 443 for ssl" do
  let(:uri) { URI 'https://api.foo.com/v1:443' }
  it { should use_ssl }
end

context "https scheme with default port" do
  it { should use_ssl }
end

context "https scheme with non-standard port" do
  let(:uri) { URI 'https://foobar.com:123456' }
  it { should use_ssl }
end
```

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/spec/httparty/connection_adapter_spec.rb

Here's my spec:

```
describe Foo do
  it 'is https' do
    adapter = HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter.new(URI(subject.base_uri))
    expect(adapter.connection.use_ssl?).to eq(true)
  end
end
```